# error - unhandledRejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, next.js

How we pass the props in the

Below code showing this err "**error - unhandledRejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead**."

```
  import React, { useEffect } from "react";
  import getConfig from 'next/config';
  import fetchUtility from 'utils/sFetchUtility';
  import axiosRetry from "axios-retry";
  import axios from "axios";
  const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

  export default async function footerAjax(){

  let trendingTopicHeader = '';
   
    trendingTopicHeader = await 
    axios.get(`${publicRuntimeConfig.nodeLocal}getRedisData/NEWS18:new_fms_system`);
    console.log("hello =" + JSON.stringify(trendingTopicHeader))

    return (<h1>navreet</h1>
    )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the footerAjax is an async function so it will return as [object Promise] when you try to render it.

You will need to handle it inside useEffect with useState like this

```
const [footer,setFooter] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchFooterAjax = async () =>{
      setFooter(await footerAjax())
    }
    fetchFooterAjax();
  },[])
```

And now you can use footer to display instead

Comment: export default  function footerAjax(){
    
    const [footer,setFooter] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchFooterAjax = async () =>{
        setFooter(await axios.get(`https://mindler-dashboard.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/products.json`));
    }
      fetchFooterAjax();
      console.log("footer "+footer)
  },[])
    

  return (
      <div className="App">
          <h1>hello</h1>
          <h6></h6>
          
    </div>
  );
}       I'm using above code ,but still unable to console    @nghe-minh

Comment: use the code inside your component, not inside the function. Import your footerAjax function to component and use it like <div>{footer}</div>